# Regression analysis with categorical variable vs. individual models per category

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data

I recently got into a discussion with a classmate that has left me a bit confused about how a linear regression model treats categorical variables.

For the context of my question, lets assume we are using the popular Iris dataset to predict Sepal Length based on Width and Species (Length ~ Width + Species).

We got into a discussion that fitting a global model with Species as an independent variable was not the same as fitting (3) separate and individual models for each species. I have always been under the impression that when adding a categorical variable such as species that has 3 levels, it would fit a separate regression model for each already? How is the different than manual separating and fitting the models for each species? If these approaches are different and yield different results, how *does* a linear regression model handle categorical levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Categorical variables are treated as a series of binary dummy variables. (Category 1? Yes/no. Category 2? yes/no. Category 3? yes/no, etc.)

The approaches are slightly different because, when you run separate regressions, you can get different y-intercepts and different coefficients on other variables (like "width" in your example). Whereas if you run one regression with a categorical variable, all the groups are forced to share the same y-intercept and the same coefficient on width.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply estimating:
$$
{\rm length}_i = \alpha_i + \beta{\rm width}
$$
So only the intercept is species-specific.

This is not the same as:
$$
{\rm length}_i = \alpha_i + \beta_i{\rm width}
$$
In which both the intercept and coefficient of width are species-specific.